# XXE prevention in Java 1.6

Tags: java, security, xml-parsing, dtd, xxe

Fellow programmers,

I'm working on a java 1.6 application that needs to be cleared of several fortify issues. The most problematic so far has been XML External Entity because there seems to be no countermeasures in 1.6. Even the OWASP cheatsheet says:

> Please use Java 7 update 67, Java 8 update 20 or above, otherwise the above countermeasures for DocumentBuilderFactory and SAXParserFactory do not work.

After some research I have been able to find some instructions and settings that would help prevent XXE, but nothing final. So any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code I'm working on.

```
    public void load(String x, int i) {

    // correcion de vulnerabilidades 26 y 29
    try {
        // Read the XML - Parse the batch class list and get the first ID.


        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

         //XXE Protection Code Goes Here
        dbf.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
        dbf.setValidating(false);
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        //End of XXE protection code


         DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         System.out.println("El documento es:"+docBuilder.isValidating());
         oXmlDoc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(x)));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Regretably, despite my best efforts, I can't bring the application to java 8 nor 7 due to sister apps and network being 1.6 too.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

**Thank you!**

Comment: xxe is somewhat an outdated, antiquated feature, switch to xsd if you can

Comment: @vtd-xml-author thank you for your reply. I didn't know xsd was safer or a better choice to avoid xxe. I'll give the code a brush up - renewal (its someone else's **old** code) If I it works come monday, i'll let you know.

Thanks for your advice